# fullcalendar timeline resourceAreaWidth

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am migrating from a 4 year old angular fullcalendar based app. Back then, i did derive the relative width of the resource area in timeline view by querying the width of the respective ".fc-resource-area" and ".fc-time-area" elements.

Now the layout has completely changed - before starting to reverse engineer the layout again and fail again with next release: Is there any official way to query the current resourceAreaWidth?

Comment: Looking through https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc I'd say no there isn't, you'll have to do the same process again.

Answer (score 0):

In any case someone needs to go the hacky way, too - this is what is running in my app as a workaround:

```
    const el = this.calendarElement.nativeElement;
    const elementResourceArea = el?.querySelector(".fc-datagrid-body");
    const elementTimeArea = el?.querySelector(".fc-timeline-body");
    const newResourceAreaWidth = elementResourceArea?.parentElement?.clientWidth ?? 0;
    const newTimeAreaWidth = elementTimeArea?.parentElement?.clientWidth ?? 0;
    if (newResourceAreaWidth === 0 || newTimeAreaWidth === 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      this.elementResourceAreaWidth !== newResourceAreaWidth ||
      this.elementTimeAreaWidth !== newTimeAreaWidth
    ) {
      this.elementResourceAreaWidth = newResourceAreaWidth;
      this.elementTimeAreaWidth = newTimeAreaWidth;
      const ratio = (newResourceAreaWidth / (newResourceAreaWidth + newTimeAreaWidth)) * 100;
      this.settings.setValue("resourceAreaWidth", "" + ratio + "%");
      this.settings.store();
    }
```